# In Excel, how can I see two worksheets in the same workbook simultaneously?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

In Excel 2007, how can I see two worksheets in the same workbook at the same time?

Comment: Not a direct answer, but when people ask me this question I often find they don't really need to see the whole of the 2nd worksheet, they are in reality only checking what happens to one or more values when they make some changes elsewhere. If that is the case, then using the Watch window (on the Formul Ribbon) is a much easier way to do it and is easier to just turn on and off once you have told it what to watch.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can have it by reading [this article](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/excel-help/view-two-or-more-worksheets-at-the-same-time-HP001217043.aspx) and [this one](http://excel.tips.net/Pages/T002688_Viewing_Two_Worksheets_At_Once.html)

Hope this will help!